# Angular/TS/JS Deep update of an existing (generic/any) object with property values of another object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am hoping to create a generic function for an update of any object by another object. We will assume that we have two objects objA and objB.

objA - the object being updated;

objB - the updating object - its property values will modify objA.

All properties are optional in both objects. We want this to be a generic function, so no specific properties or number of properties. 
All objects are assumed to be of standard - key: value structure, where value can be another nested object. We will assume the values are not arrays for the time being, (but you are welcome to address that).

If a property does not exist in objA, while present in objB, such property would be added to objA.
Otherwise, objA keeps its own properties and values (those that are NOT in objB).

Here is my code and I would welcome any corrections, adjustments, speed improvements.

```
                    /**
                     * @ngModule CommonModule
                     * @description
                     *      Deep update of an existing object with property values
                     *      of another object.
                     *      If  
                     * @param objA - the object to be updated
                     * @param objB - the object whose property values will be used
                     *                      to update 'objA'
                     */
export function updateObject(objA: Object, objB: Object) {

    Object.keys(objB).forEach(key => {
                    // if a property of the:  objB 
                    // does not exist in the: objA 
                    // add it to the:  objA 
        if (objA[key] === undefined) {
            objA[key] = objB[key];
                    // if the 2 respective properties do not match - update
        } else if (objA[key] !== objB[key]) {
                    // if a property value is another object 
                    // with 2 or more properties,
                    // process recursively 
            if (Object.keys(objA[key]).length > 1) {
                updateObject(objA[key], objB[key]);
                    // otherwise assign new value
            } else {
                objA[key] = objB[key];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using lodash or Object.assign? This is what _.merge does https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Appreciated for pointing it out, I will have a look into it.

Comment: I see there is a bunch of functionality there I was not aware of (still just learning) Marking as a good answer - no need to re-invent the wheel.